# Internal 500 error when uploading to azure storage

Tags: .net, azure, storage

I'm using the code below to upload to Azure. It's OK with a small files but a larger one (only 30MB) throws a 500 error. Azure storage explorer uploads with no problem. It seems like a time out as it takes ages to throw the error. I'm a bit stuck as the error is so vague are there any ports that need to be open? This is on my local machine, but the console will be on an Azure VM. Again any firewall settings on a VM I need to be aware of.

```
    CloudStorageAccount = New CloudStorageAccount(New StorageCredentials("account", "key"), True)
    Dim BlobClient = CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
    Dim Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("container")
    Dim CloudBlob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference("forcast/forcast.csv")
    CloudBlob.UploadFromFile("C:\HadoopTestData\forcast.csv", IO.FileMode.Open)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be getting this error because you're trying to upload a very large file in one go. When uploading large files, it is recommended that you upload them by splitting them in chunks. In Windows Azure terms, you would need to split the file into smaller blocks and upload those blocks using [`PutBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblock.aspx) method. Once all blocks are uploaded, you would then commit these blocks using [`PutBlockList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblocklist.aspx) method. If you trace the upload request through Fiddler when you're uploading using Azure Storage Explorer, you should notice that it is doing the same thing.

> I'm a bit stuck as the error is so vague are there any ports that need
>   to be open? This is on my local machine, but the console will be on an
>   Azure VM. Again any firewall settings on a VM I need to be aware of.

Since interaction with Windows Azure Storage happens via REST API (i.e. either on port 80 or 443), you need not worry about opening up any additional ports in the firewall.